# Introductory Topology Book Recommendation for Economics

Tags: general-topology, analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

Would you please share your 2 cent on book recommendation for introductory topology book to graduate student in Economics.

Have exposure to the first half of the yearlong analysis course in the following books:

***Baby Rudin.***

***Understanding Analysis by Abbott.***

***The Way of Analysis by Strichartz.***

***Yet Another Introduction to Analysis by Bryant.***

The main reason for searching a good introductory topology book is to gain formal exposure to concepts like connected spaces, metri, pseudo metric spaces, products/quotients, separation axiom, ordered sets, compactification, etc.

My friend recommended ***Real Analysis with Economic Applications*** by Ok and if anybody had exposure with his book, also please share your experience with the book.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what you're getting at by mentioning you're in economics, but if you have some first year analysis then Munkres' book is a fantastic introduction.

Comment: Jake, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It starts off with some set theory to get your background up to par before it covers the point-set topology topics you covered, and then moves onto algebraic topology if you have any interest in that.

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities:

[**Infinite Dimensional Analysis: A Hitchhiker's Guide**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540326960) by Charalambos D. Aliprantis and Kim Border

[**Topological Spaces: Including a Treatment of Multi-Valued Functions, Vector Spaces and Convexity**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486696537) by Claude Berge

Comment: Dave, thanks for the suggestion. Are you an economist?

Comment: I'm not an economist -- I've only taken a couple of introductory economics courses (micro and macro) as electives when I was an undergraduate. I have a copy of Berge's book (has topics I'm interested in, cluster sets of functions and set valued analysis topics) and I remembered that he was in (or at least he wrote for) economics, and the other is a book I've seen in a nearby university library and have thought I might buy one day because it appears to have nice expositions of a lot of topics I'm somewhat interested in.

Answer (score -1):

You may consult the following two books which are very fundamental & easy to understand;

1) Topology & Modern Analysis  by  G. F. Simmon
2) General Topology            by  Seymour Lipschutz